# Need arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Need arrayformula for this query in google sheets

=ifna(query('B. Projects New'!$A$3:$M, "select H where G='Plan_294492' and A='"&A2&"'"),"-")

I need your quick help in this.

Comment: If the formula is only returning one result, you should use a lookup function such as XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As said, will work for one value:

```
=BYROW (A2:A,LAMBDA(each,ifna(query('B. Projects New'!$A$3:$M, "select H where G='Plan_294492' and A='"& each &"'"),"-")))
```

If there are several equal queries, you can do a single query with your conditions in G and A in an auxiliary sheet, and then do a Lookup,

It will be much less consuming